# Minipages' vertical alignment

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

I use three minipages so to make a table and two images be placed next to each  other and although the images are in the right place the table is placed much lower producing an ugly result. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
$V_{c}(Low)$ & $mV$ & $0$\\
\hline
$V_{c}(High)$ & $V$ & $5.6$\\
\hline
$T_{d}$ & $ns$ & $30$\\
\hline
$T_{r}$ & $ns$ & $30$\\
\hline 
$T_{sd}$ & $ns$ & $780$\\
\hline 
$T_{f}$ & $ns$ & $240$\\
\hline 
$F_{max}$ & $kHz$ & $570$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{A1.JPG}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{A2.JPG}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: The `\abovebaseline` and `\belowbaseline` macros of `stackengine` could be of use here.  With these, you don't specify how much to move the item up or down, but rather specify where you want it to end up, relative to the baseline.

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? If not, can you explain what is missing?

Comment: Yes they did. The only thing I can't quite understand is why I had to use some other way and my code didn't work aligning perfectly the table with the images, considering that as it is mentioned here a table is a sort of a minipage.

Comment: @Adam I edited my answer with an (attempted) explanation and another way of doing this. Also, to make sure people are notified of comments here, write `@<username>` as I did here. (The person who owns the post is always notified, but not everyone else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why your code doesn't work.

This has to do with how this vertical alignment actually works. Consider first the following code and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some text then a table \begin{tabular}{c}
1 \\2 \\ 3 \\ 4
\end{tabular}
then some more text and an image \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-10x16}.    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The point of this is how the table and image is placed relative to the baseline of the surrounding text -- the `tabular` is vertically centred, the image is placed on the baseline, and so sticks above the line.

Now what the `t`/`b` position specifier for the `minipage`s refer to is not actually the top/bottom edge of the `minipage`, as I understand it, but the *baseline of the first/last line of text* in the `minipage`. In the `minipage` with the table, the baseline is in the middle of the table, as you can see from the image above. But in the `minipage`s with the images, the baseline is at the bottom of the image. As a result, the bottom of the images are aligned with the middle of the table.

#### Suggestion 1

As suggested by daleif, I removed the `minipage` for the `tabular` in the below code.

If you set the alignment of the right `minipage`s to `c`enter it looks better, i.e.

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
```

The `tabular` has `c` as alignment by default.

To top-align them, you can set the position of both `tabular` and `minipage`s to `t`, and set the inner position (third optional argument) of the `minipage`s with the images to `b`. That is, you'll have

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{...}
```

for the table and

```
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{5cm}
```

for the `minipage`s.

#### Suggestion 2

If you add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can change the vertical alignment of images, relative to the baseline, with the optional argument `valign=<t/c/b>` to `\includegraphics`. Then you can ditch the `minipage`s altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} s S }
\toprule
V_{c}(\text{Low}) & \milli\volt & 0\\
V_{c}(\text{High}) & \volt & 5.6\\
T_{d} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{r} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{sd} & \nano\s & 780\\
T_{f} & \nano\s & 240\\
F_{\text{max}} & \kilo\hertz & 570\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hspace{1em}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

#### Some notes about the table.

Not really part of the question, but I added a suggestion for how you could write the table in the code below, you see the result in the image.

The column specification has been changed to `{>{$}c<{$} s S }`. When loading the `array` package you can use `>{}`/`<{}` to insert stuff at the beginning/end of the cell, by doing the above the effect is that each cell is set in math mode. That saves you some typing.

For the second column, note that units should generally not be written in italics. You could simply remove all the math mode, and it would be a lot better. Here I used an `s` column from `siunitx`, which allows one to use the unit macros from `siunitx` to typeset the units.

The final column is an `S` column, also from `siunitx`, which aligns the numbers at the decimal marker. Not sure if is an improvement in this case, but I thought I'd add it as a tip.

In the first column, you'll notice I set words 'Low' and 'High' and 'max' in text mode. This is mostly a question of convention I suppose, but I think descriptive words, as opposed to variable names, should not be italic. I also removed all the vertical lines, and added a thicker horizontal line (from `booktabs`) above and below. It makes the table less cluttered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} s S }
\toprule
V_{c}(\text{Low}) & \milli\volt & 0\\
V_{c}(\text{High}) & \volt & 5.6\\
T_{d} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{r} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{sd} & \nano\s & 780\\
T_{f} & \nano\s & 240\\
F_{\text{max}} & \kilo\hertz & 570\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}c<{$} s S }
\toprule
V_{c}(\text{Low}) & \milli\volt & 0\\
V_{c}(\text{High}) & \volt & 5.6\\
T_{d} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{r} & \nano\s & 30\\
T_{sd} & \nano\s & 780\\
T_{f} & \nano\s & 240\\
F_{\text{max}} & \kilo\hertz & 570\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One can avoid the `minipages` altogether, using `\abovebaseline` and `\belowbaseline` of the `stackengine` package.  Note the syntax at the end of the MWE.  In this case, I saved each item in its own stackbox only so that, if the centered output was required, additional calculation was required using the box heights.  Otherwise, the columns could have been output directly with the syntax shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\savestack{\colA}{
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}
\hline
$V_{c}(Low)$ & $mV$ & $0$\\
\hline
$V_{c}(High)$ & $V$ & $5.6$\\
\hline
$T_{d}$ & $ns$ & $30$\\
\hline
$T_{r}$ & $ns$ & $30$\\
\hline 
$T_{sd}$ & $ns$ & $780$\\
\hline 
$T_{f}$ & $ns$ & $240$\\
\hline 
$F_{max}$ & $kHz$ & $570$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\savestack{\colB}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{A1.JPG}}

\savestack{\colC}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=2.5cm]{A2.JPG}}

\colA\ \abovebaseline[.5\ht\colAcontent-.5\ht\colBcontent]{\colB}\ 
  \abovebaseline[.5\ht\colAcontent-.5\ht\colCcontent]{\colC}

\colA\ \colB\ \colC

\belowbaseline{\colA}\ \belowbaseline{\colB}\ \belowbaseline{\colC}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tabular` is already a sort of minipage (you may want to use `\begin{tabular[t]{...}`). By default it has it baseline in the middle, the surrounding `minipage` does not alter this as the `tabular` behaves as a single line (sort of). The images are aligned on the base like and it mush taller than that.

You might want to play with the `adjustbox` package, it has many useful features for aligning stuff.

Also a small plea: please post something we can copy'n'paste and use without editing it. You have no preamble, and we of course do not have your images. For images you could use `\rule{length}{length}`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about the editing part so I won't neglect it the the next time. But sorry I didn't understand why all three items didn't aligh horizontally if the table is a sort of a minipage but the latter went down in the page even though the images in the minipages were up and aligned.

Comment: See what happens if you use `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`, and then what happens if you change all four `[t]` to `[b]`