# Using minipage in two page layout

Tags: minipage

Here I am making a two page news letter.
I am facing some issues with minipage.
Here is the code snippet 
From above if I remove comments line 60, 61, then every thing is aligned.
What is going wrong
I don't know how to attach file

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=2.2in, left=0.7in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false, pdfborder=0]{hyperref}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
%-------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{top.eps}
\LLCornerWallPaper{1}{bottom.eps}
%-------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.30\linewidth}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{itemize}%[itemsep=4pt]
\item Serial Number: 5
\item April 2015
\item \href{http://www.google.com}{www.google.com}
\end{itemize}
\lineskip 5em%
\includegraphics{a.eps}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.66\linewidth}
\section*{Header 1}
\subsection*{Header 2}

What do the world's most innovative cities -- from London, to Helsinki, and Seoul to Amsterdam -- have in common? Each has a uniquely local spirit, but has developed an entrepreneurial edge compared to global peers.

Is it the amount of money they invest in local startups, how they regulate new business models or how they use data to govern? New research published today by innovation charity Nesta, Accenture and the Future Cities Catapult may have some answers. "We set out to measure the quality of the policy environment -- how well city governments are supporting the growth of a tech community," says John Gibson, study co-author and Director of Government Innovation at Nesta.

The research team evaluated 40 city governments and crunched 1,400 data points. Their big goal: to help policymakers make entrepreneurs' lives easier. According to their report, the top performing cities are New York, London and Helsinki. "Helsinki came as a surprise," Gibson says. One of the most unique innovations the city has is an Uber-like mobility-on-demand strategy so wherever you are in the city centre, it delivers you the ideal route by converging all public and private transport options, and even deviating bus routes around you.

Amsterdam, which was fifth on the list, was another pleasant surprise, according to Gibson. "They have city-sponsored smart districts, co-working locations and investment funds. The government just launched their Startup Amsterdam strategy to promote the community globally," he says.

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\footnotesize
%\caption{Some Caption} \\
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Select Coverage}} \\[1mm]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(out of total of 41 Tables)} \\[1mm]
\hline
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Time Series}} \\[1mm]
\hline
&Earliest&Latest \\ \hline
Annual finance statements&2006&2014 \\ \hline
Half-yearly finance statements&2008&2015 \\ \hline
Quarterly finance statements&2009&2015 \\ \hline
Segment-wise information&2005&2014 \\ \hline
Related party transactions&2007&2015 \\ \hline
Interested party transactions&2010&2015 \\ \hline
Equity ownership pattern&2007&2015 \\ \hline
Auditors, Bankers, Managers, Trustees&2007&2014 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.30\linewidth}
%Some text here
%
\includegraphics{b.eps}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.66\linewidth}
\section*{Header3}

"They are really going gangbusters." Gibson's team analysed the cities by identifying nine roles that a city can play to support local entrepreneurship -- from regulator and customer, to host and connector. "For instance, take the role of customer -- cities spend £4.5 trillion a year buying goods and services, so we measured whether it's done in a way that's open and accessible for startups, or locked down with incumbents," Gibson explains. Sao Paolo was one of the best examples. All you need to do to qualify for a government procurement contract is to show you've paid your taxes -- no complicated invoices or legal minefields.

"They have a rule that says startups get preferential treatment if their price is up to 10 per cent more that that of large companies," Gibson says. "They're using their procurement system to pull through great ideas from small companies. London should copy that policy." In Tokyo on the other hand, startups wouldn't dare compete for government business -- the policies are set up to bring in large corporates, over small businesses.

Once the data was crunched, the report clustered the 40 cities into four tiers of performance, based on their shared characteristics and their overall profiles. In the bottom tier are the 'Experimenters' -- cities like Jakarta, Istanbul and Nairobi which are still testing the waters with new e-government strategies, like Jakarta's mobile reporting app for citizens' complaints. In the top tier, or Front Runners, London came in behind New York, because it hasn't integrated an entrepreneurial element into leadership yet -- "It doesn't have an innovation team in city hall or a Chief Technology Officer, like many North American cities," Gibson says.

"Also, where London put in £1.5m into digital skills education, New York's mayor De Blasio committed \$70m." London was however, the first to get its act together for open data, which led directly to the founding of startups like Citymapper, which adapted the data into a business model. "Citymapper built a product that allows you to navigate city transport, and is now in 20 different cities. There's a lovely cause and effect there," Gibson says. Neil Rimer, cofounder of investment firm Index Ventures, who wasn't involved in the research, thinks the report will have a practical impact.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am getting black page colour in the background, regardless, whether I use `\usepackage[demo]{graphics}` or comment out the `\includegraphics` ... is this correct? ;-)

Comment: I am unable to attach the needed eps files. If you put some dummy eps files with name top.eps, bottom.eps, a.eps, b.eps. it should work.

Comment: The \includegraphics is the main Item of the problem

Comment: I am using pdflatex for pdf compilation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the top of `b.eps` isn't aligned with the `\section` in the adjacent minipage. The reason for this is the meaning of the `t` argument to `minipage`s. The `t` does not mean that the very top of the `minipage`s will be aligned, but that the *baseline of the first line of text* in each `minipage` is aligned. You may notice that the bottom of the image aligns with the baseline of the section title.

To modify that you could for example change the `minipage` arguments to

```
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{.30\linewidth}
```

as in [minipage environment with bottom-aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132080/minipage-environment-with-bottom-aligned/132240#132240), or you could add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use `\includegraphics[valign=t]{b}`, as mentioned in e.g. [Minipages' vertical alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166063/minipages-vertical-alignment/166070#166070).

However, it seems to me as `minipage` might not be the best route for your use. It doesn't allow for page breaks, for example. Therefore I suggest an alternative method with `\marginpar`s.

Some notes:

- I changed the left margin to `3in` and set `marginparwidth=2.5in`.
- The `marginfix` package is loaded to improve positioning of `\marginpar`s.
- `\reversemarginpar` places the `\marginpar`s in the left margin, as opposed to the default right.
- I also modified the table to use less horizontal rules, and the rules of the `booktabs` package instead of the default `\hline`.
- I commented the `wallpaper` stuff because I couldn't be bothered to find an appropriate image, and because it was unrelated to the problem as I understood it. If it does matter, please comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=2.2in, left=3in, right=1in,marginparwidth=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false, pdfborder=0]{hyperref}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
%-------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
%\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{top.eps}
%\LLCornerWallPaper{1}{bottom.eps}
%-------------------

\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

\marginpar{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{itemize}%[itemsep=4pt]
\item Serial Number: 5
\item April 2015
\item \href{http://www.google.com}{www.google.com}
\end{itemize}
\lineskip 5em%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
}
\section*{Header 1}
\subsection*{Header 2}

What do the world's most innovative cities -- from London, to Helsinki, and Seoul to Amsterdam -- have in common? Each has a uniquely local spirit, but has developed an entrepreneurial edge compared to global peers.

Is it the amount of money they invest in local startups, how they regulate new business models or how they use data to govern? New research published today by innovation charity Nesta, Accenture and the Future Cities Catapult may have some answers. "We set out to measure the quality of the policy environment -- how well city governments are supporting the growth of a tech community," says John Gibson, study co-author and Director of Government Innovation at Nesta.

The research team evaluated 40 city governments and crunched 1,400 data points. Their big goal: to help policymakers make entrepreneurs' lives easier. According to their report, the top performing cities are New York, London and Helsinki. "Helsinki came as a surprise," Gibson says. One of the most unique innovations the city has is an Uber-like mobility-on-demand strategy so wherever you are in the city centre, it delivers you the ideal route by converging all public and private transport options, and even deviating bus routes around you.

Amsterdam, which was fifth on the list, was another pleasant surprise, according to Gibson. "They have city-sponsored smart districts, co-working locations and investment funds. The government just launched their Startup Amsterdam strategy to promote the community globally," he says.

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\footnotesize\centering
%\caption{Some Caption} \\
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Select Coverage}} \\[1mm]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(out of total of 41 Tables)} \\[1mm]
\midrule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Time Series}} \\[1mm]
&Earliest&Latest \\ \midrule
Annual finance statements&2006&2014 \\ 
Half-yearly finance statements&2008&2015 \\ 
Quarterly finance statements&2009&2015 \\ 
Segment-wise information&2005&2014 \\ 
Related party transactions&2007&2015 \\ 
Interested party transactions&2010&2015 \\ 
Equity ownership pattern&2007&2015 \\ 
Auditors, Bankers, Managers, Trustees&2007&2014 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par}

\newpage

\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\section*{Header3}

"They are really going gangbusters." Gibson's team analysed the cities by identifying nine roles that a city can play to support local entrepreneurship -- from regulator and customer, to host and connector. "For instance, take the role of customer -- cities spend £4.5 trillion a year buying goods and services, so we measured whether it's done in a way that's open and accessible for startups, or locked down with incumbents," Gibson explains. Sao Paolo was one of the best examples. All you need to do to qualify for a government procurement contract is to show you've paid your taxes -- no complicated invoices or legal minefields.

"They have a rule that says startups get preferential treatment if their price is up to 10 per cent more that that of large companies," Gibson says. "They're using their procurement system to pull through great ideas from small companies. London should copy that policy." In Tokyo on the other hand, startups wouldn't dare compete for government business -- the policies are set up to bring in large corporates, over small businesses.

Once the data was crunched, the report clustered the 40 cities into four tiers of performance, based on their shared characteristics and their overall profiles. In the bottom tier are the 'Experimenters' -- cities like Jakarta, Istanbul and Nairobi which are still testing the waters with new e-government strategies, like Jakarta's mobile reporting app for citizens' complaints. In the top tier, or Front Runners, London came in behind New York, because it hasn't integrated an entrepreneurial element into leadership yet -- "It doesn't have an innovation team in city hall or a Chief Technology Officer, like many North American cities," Gibson says.

"Also, where London put in £1.5m into digital skills education, New York's mayor De Blasio committed \$70m." London was however, the first to get its act together for open data, which led directly to the founding of startups like Citymapper, which adapted the data into a business model. "Citymapper built a product that allows you to navigate city transport, and is now in 20 different cities. There's a lovely cause and effect there," Gibson says. Neil Rimer, cofounder of investment firm Index Ventures, who wasn't involved in the research, thinks the report will have a practical impact.

\end{document}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=2.2in, left=3in, right=1in,marginparwidth=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false, pdfborder=0]{hyperref}

\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

\marginpar{%
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{itemize}%[itemsep=4pt]
\item Serial Number: 5
\item April 2015
\item \href{http://www.google.com}{www.google.com}
\end{itemize}
\lineskip 5em%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
}

\section*{Header 1}
\subsection*{Header 2}

What do the world's most innovative cities -- from London, to Helsinki, and Seoul to Amsterdam -- have in common? Each has a uniquely local spirit, but has developed an entrepreneurial edge compared to global peers.

Is it the amount of money they invest in local startups, how they regulate new business models or how they use data to govern? New research published today by innovation charity Nesta, Accenture and the Future Cities Catapult may have some answers. "We set out to measure the quality of the policy environment -- how well city governments are supporting the growth of a tech community," says John Gibson, study co-author and Director of Government Innovation at Nesta.

The research team evaluated 40 city governments and crunched 1,400 data points. Their big goal: to help policymakers make entrepreneurs' lives easier. According to their report, the top performing cities are New York, London and Helsinki. "Helsinki came as a surprise," Gibson says. One of the most unique innovations the city has is an Uber-like mobility-on-demand strategy so wherever you are in the city centre, it delivers you the ideal route by converging all public and private transport options, and even deviating bus routes around you.

Amsterdam, which was fifth on the list, was another pleasant surprise, according to Gibson. "They have city-sponsored smart districts, co-working locations and investment funds. The government just launched their Startup Amsterdam strategy to promote the community globally," he says.


{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\footnotesize\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Select Coverage}} \\[1mm]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{(out of total of 41 Tables)} \\[1mm]
\midrule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Time Series}} \\[1mm]
&Earliest&Latest \\ \midrule
Annual finance statements&2006&2014 \\ 
Half-yearly finance statements&2008&2015 \\ 
Quarterly finance statements&2009&2015 \\ 
Segment-wise information&2005&2014 \\ 
Related party transactions&2007&2015 \\ 
Interested party transactions&2010&2015 \\ 
Equity ownership pattern&2007&2015 \\ 
Auditors, Bankers, Managers, Trustees&2007&2014 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}\par
}

\newpage

\section*{Header3}
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
"They are really going gangbusters." Gibson's team analysed the cities by identifying nine roles that a city can play to support local entrepreneurship -- from regulator and customer, to host and connector. "For instance, take the role of customer -- cities spend £4.5 trillion a year buying goods and services, so we measured whether it's done in a way that's open and accessible for startups, or locked down with incumbents," Gibson explains. Sao Paolo was one of the best examples. All you need to do to qualify for a government procurement contract is to show you've paid your taxes -- no complicated invoices or legal minefields.

"They have a rule that says startups get preferential treatment if their price is up to 10 per cent more that that of large companies," Gibson says. "They're using their procurement system to pull through great ideas from small companies. London should copy that policy." In Tokyo on the other hand, startups wouldn't dare compete for government business -- the policies are set up to bring in large corporates, over small businesses.

Once the data was crunched, the report clustered the 40 cities into four tiers of performance, based on their shared characteristics and their overall profiles. In the bottom tier are the 'Experimenters' -- cities like Jakarta, Istanbul and Nairobi which are still testing the waters with new e-government strategies, like Jakarta's mobile reporting app for citizens' complaints. In the top tier, or Front Runners, London came in behind New York, because it hasn't integrated an entrepreneurial element into leadership yet -- "It doesn't have an innovation team in city hall or a Chief Technology Officer, like many North American cities," Gibson says.

"Also, where London put in £1.5m into digital skills education, New York's mayor De Blasio committed \$70m." London was however, the first to get its act together for open data, which led directly to the founding of startups like Citymapper, which adapted the data into a business model. "Citymapper built a product that allows you to navigate city transport, and is now in 20 different cities. There's a lovely cause and effect there," Gibson says. Neil Rimer, cofounder of investment firm Index Ventures, who wasn't involved in the research, thinks the report will have a practical impact.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi,

thank you very much.

I since I am a beginner in LaTex. I will take some time to digest the reply.

Will be replying again.